# Implementando função do tipo month

Tags: c++, data, conversão

Bom dia galera blz?

estava implementando uma função do tipo Month que retorna Month
tentei usar static_cast para converter para o tipo Month mas da erros de conversão para o mesmo. O programa é este abaixo:

```
#include <regex>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

enum Month
{
  Jan = 1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
};

// structured binding, Datastructure for string to num conversion in month(.i.e."Mar" Month to 3)
std::array<std::pair<std::string, Month>, 12> monthinfo = 
{
    std::make_pair("Jan", Month::Jan),
    std::make_pair("Feb", Month::Feb),
    std::make_pair("Mar", Month::Mar),
    std::make_pair("Apr", Month::Apr),
    std::make_pair("May", Month::May),
    std::make_pair("Jun", Month::Jun),
    std::make_pair("Jul", Month::Jul),
    std::make_pair("Aug", Month::Aug),
    std::make_pair("Sep", Month::Sep),
    std::make_pair("Oct", Month::Oct),
    std::make_pair("Nov", Month::Nov),
    std::make_pair("Dec", Month::Dec)
};

// concrete daytime structure to store the data
//template<typename T1, typename T2 = std::string>
template<class T1, class T2 = std::string>
struct DayTime
{
    T1 day      = T1();
    T1 month    = T1();
    T1 year     = T1();
    T1 hour     = T1();
    T1 min      = T1();
    T1 second   = T1();
    T2 daystr   = T2();
    T2 dtstring = T2();
};


// main class which would fetech/parse the current time and provide to the client
class CurrentDateTime
{
   DayTime<std::string> ParseDateTime(const std::string&);
   void StrToNumber(const DayTime<std::string>&);
   Month GetMonth(const std::string&);
   DayTime<int> dt;

 public:

    CurrentDateTime();
    virtual ~CurrentDateTime(){};

    int      GetDay() const { return dt.day;    }
    Month  GetMonth() const { return dt.month;  }
    int     GetYear() const { return dt.year;   }
    int     GetHour() const { return dt.hour;   }
    int      GetMin() const { return dt.min;    }
    int   GetSecond() const { return dt.second; }
    std::string   GetDayStr() const { return dt.daystr; }
};

CurrentDateTime::CurrentDateTime()
{
    //fetch/store current local-daytime information
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t cstyle_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    char* cstyleinfo = std::ctime(&cstyle_t);
    // copy(deep) the data into the std::string as ::ctime() provides static data 
    // which might be overwritten in case someone call it again.
    std::string currentinfo(cstyleinfo);

    //parse/store  the information
    auto dtstr = ParseDateTime(currentinfo);
    StrToNumber(dtstr);
}


DayTime<std::string> CurrentDateTime::ParseDateTime(const std::string& information)
{
    DayTime<std::string> info;
    std::regex dtimeregex(R"(^(\w{3}) (\w{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\d{4}))");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(information, match, dtimeregex)) 
    {
        // Match the group and subgroups by regex parser.
        auto index = 0;
        info.dtstring = match[index++];
        info.daystr   = match[index++];
        info.month    = match[index++];
        info.day      = match[index++];
        info.hour     = match[index++];
        info.min      = match[index++];
        info.second   = match[index++];
        info.year     = match[index++];
    }

    return info;
}

Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const std::string& input) const 
{
    for (const auto& itr : monthinfo) 
    {
        if (itr.first == input)
      return itr.second;
      //return static_cast<Month>(itr.second);
    }
    assert(false && "Invalid month name");
    // Or return a default month if it makes sense.
    // Another possibility is extending the enum Month to 
    // add an invalid dummy value, throwing an exception, etc.
}

void CurrentDateTime::StrToNumber(const DayTime<std::string>& information)
{
    dt.dtstring = information.dtstring;
    dt.daystr   = information.daystr;
    dt.month    = GetMonth(information.month);

    dt.day      = std::stoi(information.day.c_str());
    dt.hour     = std::stoi(information.hour.c_str());
    dt.min      = std::stoi(information.min.c_str());
    dt.second   = std::stoi(information.second.c_str());
    dt.year     = std::stoi(information.year.c_str());
}


int main()
{
  CurrentDateTime current = *new CurrentDateTime();

    std::cout << "\n\tCurrent Day....: " << current.GetDayStr()
              << "\n\tCurrent Date...: " << current.GetDay()
              << "\n\tCurrent Month..: " << current.GetMonth()
              << "\n\tCurrent Year...: " << current.GetYear()
              << "\n\tCurrent Hour...: " << current.GetHour()
              << "\n\tCurrent Min....: " << current.GetMin()
              << "\n\tCurrent Second.: " << current.GetSecond() 
              << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

pois o programa deveria retornar algo como:

```
    Current Day....: Tue
    Current Date...: 23
    Current Month..: 1
    Current Year...: 2018
    Current Hour...: 8
    Current Min....: 50
    Current Second.: 29
```

mas ele gera o seguinte erro abaixo:

```
Ex2.cxx: In member function ‘Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth() const’:
Ex2.cxx:62:49: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Month’ [-fpermissive]
             Month  GetMonth() const { return dt.month;  }
                                              ~~~^~~~~
Ex2.cxx: At global scope:
Ex2.cxx:108:7: error: prototype for ‘Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const string&) const’ does not match any in class ‘CurrentDateTime’
 Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const std::string& input) const
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ex2.cxx:62:20: error: candidates are: Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth() const
             Month  GetMonth() const { return dt.month;  }
                    ^~~~~~~~
Ex2.cxx:53:10: error:                 Month CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const string&)
    Month GetMonth(const std::string&);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem dois problemas que estão gerando esses erros:

### 1) Conversão entre inteiros e enumerações

Na linha 62 você está tentando converter um valor `dt.month` (que é do tipo inteiro) para um valor do tipo `Month` que é uma enumeração. Embora as enumerações em C++ sejam armazenadas como valores inteiros internamente, esse tipo de conversão não é feito implicitamente (porque o valor inteiro poderia cair fora dos valores da enumeração). Ou você cria uma função para fazer isso (que é a opção mais correta e segura) ou simplesmente substitui a linha

```
Month  GetMonth() const { return dt.month;  }
```

Por

```
Month  GetMonth() const { return static_cast<Month>(dt.month);  }
```

Essa é a opção mais rápida de resolver o problema.

### 2) Declaração de método diferente da implementação

Você está declarando o método `CurrentDateTime::GetMonth(const std::string&)` na classe `CurrentDateTime` sem `const`, mas está tentando definir esse método usando `const` mais embaixo. Você deve decidir o que quer. A melhor opção parece ser simplesmente adicionar `const` à declaração do método, isto é, substituir a linha

```
Month GetMonth(const std::string&);
```

Por

```
Month GetMonth(const std::string&) const;
```

A versão corrigida do seu código está aqui: https://ideone.com/IxbffB

P.S.: As pessoas por aqui não gostam muito quando você simplesmente copia código com erro e espera que outros debuguem pra você. Da próxima vez, se você tiver uma dúvida sobre algum dos tópicos que gerou o erro, coloque a dúvida sobre o tópico como pergunta `;)`

Comment: então em relação a declaração diferente da implementação fiz retornando int e esta funcionando..

Comment: Retornando `int` funciona porque você está fazendo o `static_cast` implicitamente.